# Error calling RPC method create_wallet with curl

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, monerod-commands

I have a remote node setup with RPC enabled and `restricted_rpc` set to false. I am trying to create a new wallet remotely, but I'm getting the response: **Error: method not found**

```
curl -u 123:abc--digest -X POST http://xxxx.com:18089/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"create_wallet","params":{"filename":"mytestwallet","password":"mytestpassword","language":"English"}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Alternatively, how can I do it locally using `monerod` that connects to a remote node? Basically I don't want to download the entire monero blockchain, but still be able to create wallets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create wallets using the *daemon* RPC (`monerod`). For that functionality, you would use the `monero-wallet-rpc` calling it's method [create_wallet](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet).

Alternatively, if you just wanted to create a *local* wallet (so not on the same host as your remote node), you would use `monero-wallet-cli` locally and have that connect to the remote node using `--daemon-address host:port`.

Comment: I'm using --digest with curl, because I'm following the instructions from the monero website: https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html

Comment: I could be mistaken on the digest part or the docs could be outdated. Either way, with curl, just specifying `-u user:pass` works without `--digest`. I'll update this answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you're asking a *node* to create a wallet ? A node cannot. A node doesn't deal in wallets, just in blockchain. Ask your local wallet, which in turns talks to the node hosted wherever.

Comment: "Ask your local wallet, which in turns talks to the node hosed wherever." <- The OP shows they are trying to use the wallet RPC method create_wallet, which is specifically designed to allow creating of a wallet on a remote machine.

Comment: If you *read* the post, it says "I have a remote node setup". Node is not wallet. Maybe there's a wallet too, but it was not mentioned, so there is no reason to assume there is one.

Comment: I did read it. OP is stating multiple things.. That they're using a node but also trying to call a wallet RPC method. Also trying to create a remote wallet "I am trying to create a new wallet remotely". Your answer does not address this.